# trained in python, test in C- is it possible?

Tags: c, simulation, python-c-api, regsvr32

I recently work on prediction model with python SVR module.

Since I am simuatlion guy - I usually use simulation tool- it is easy to compute temperature with given property, but it is hard when you don't know its property - my situation is: I would like to know the temperature of an unknown point , it is very hard to give a property.

That is why I used prediction model- it worked so good.

The variables for prediction model can be monitored on simulation tool,

so I would like to apply this prediction model(saved as form of pickel) with its user code .

the problem is it only allow C for user code.. have you guy tried this case?

export trained model by python as pickel -> apply with C to predict the value .

Well Actually I never tried C before, so i am looking for a library which act same as SVR on python..

Comment: You're probably looking at [embedding Python into C](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html), or, now that you know the parameters, [retraining your model in libsvm](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/issues/184).